# mypy TypeVar include bound class as well as subclasses

Tags: static, mypy

```
class Super:
    @classmethod
    def instantiate(cls) -> What goes here?:
        return cls()

class Sub(Super):
    pass

class Sub2(Super):
    pass
```

When writing typehints, what's the canonical way to say a method should return an instance of the super class or any of its subclasses. Closest I could find is `TypeVar("Super", bound="Super")` but this still raises an error for the Super class in mypy

Answer (score 1):

here you can use [typing.Type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type) to type-hint `cls` like this:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Type

C = TypeVar("C")

class Super:
    @classmethod
    def instantiate(cls: Type[C]) -> C:
        return cls()

class Sub(Super):
    pass

class Sub2(Super):
    pass

reveal_type(Sub.instantiate()) # note: Revealed type is 'tmp.Sub*'
reveal_type(Sub2.instantiate()) # note: Revealed type is 'tmp.Sub2*'
```